# UIAlertView not working is Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

My Xamarin.native project targetting Android & iOS. I am not able to show Alert in Xamarin.iOS; thou the following code works fine on Xamarin.Android.

### In PCL:

```
public interface IDialogProvider
{
    void ShowMessage(string title, string message, string dismissButtonTitle, Action dismissed);
    void Confirm(string title, string message, string okButtonTitle, string dismissButtonTitle, Action confirmed, Action dismissed);
}
```

======================================

### In Xamarin.iOS

```
public class TouchDialogProvider : IDialogProvider
{
    public void ShowMessage(string title, string message, string dismissButtonTitle, Action dismissed)
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(dismissButtonTitle, UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        action => { if (null != dismissed) { dismissed.Invoke(); } }));
    }

public void Confirm(string title, string message, string okButtonTitle, string dismissButtonTitle, Action confirmed, Action dismissed)
{
    var alertView = new UIAlertView(title, message, null, dismissButtonTitle, okButtonTitle);
    alertView.Clicked += (object sender, UIButtonEventArgs e) => {
    if (e.ButtonIndex == 1 & null != confirmed)
        { confirmed.Invoke(); }
        if (e.ButtonIndex == 0 & null != dismissed)
            { dismissed.Invoke(); } };
    alertView.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are never presenting the view controller in your `ShowMessage` method:

```
public void ShowMessage(string title, string message, string dismissButtonTitle, Action dismissed)
{
    var alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
    alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(dismissButtonTitle, UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
    action => { if (null != dismissed) { dismissed.Invoke(); } }));
    var rootVC = UIApplication.SharedApplication.Windows[0].RootViewController;
    rootVC.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
}
```

The other `Confirm` method should to be changed from `UIAlertView` to an `UIAlertController` as UIAlertView has been deprecated since iOS 9.

Comment: This throws 
{UIKit.UIKitThreadAccessException: UIKit Consistency error: you are calling a UIKit method that can only be invoked from the UI thread

Comment: @MukteswarPatnaik That is a standard error message if you are calling those functions from a background thread, wrap it in a InvokeOnMainThread call: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45261882/4984832

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an easier way to make an alert popup. You can try it like this:

```
UIAlertView alert = new UIAlertView()
{
    Title = "Network error",
    Message = "Please check your internert connection"
};
alert.AddButton("Cancel");
alert.AddButton("OK");
alert.Show();
alert.Clicked += Alert_Clicked;

void Alert_Clicked(object sender, UIButtonEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.ButtonIndex == 1 )
   {
      //your action on alert dialog OK button click
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use below one to create alert, I always use this one only.

```
    void CreateAlert(string title, string buttonTitle, RelayCommand buttonCommand, string error, RelayCommand closeButtonCommand = null)
    {
        var elements = new List<InfoDialogElement>{
            new InfoDialogElement
            {
                Type = InfoDialogElementTypeEnum.Text,
                MarginTop = 25,
                MarginBottom = 25,
                SideMargin = 0,
                Info = error,
                TextSize = 16,
                Font = FontStyleEnum.OoredooHeavy
            }
        };
        var dialog = new OoInfoDialog(title, buttonTitle, buttonCommand, elements);
        if (closeButtonCommand != null)
            dialog.CloseCommand = closeButtonCommand;

        if (DialogBeingPresented != null)
            DialogBeingPresented.PresentDialog(dialog, UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 230));
        else
        {
            var parentViewController = AppDelegate.Current.Window.RootViewController;
            if (parentViewController != null)
            {
                if (parentViewController is UINavigationController)
                {
                    (parentViewController as UINavigationController).TopViewController.PresentDialog(dialog, UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 230));
                } else
                {
                    parentViewController.PresentDialog(dialog, UIColor.FromRGBA(0, 0, 0, 230));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Show your AlertView as PresentViewController

```
InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        var alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(dismissButtonTitle, UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => { if (null != dismissed) { dismissed.Invoke(); } }));
        PresentViewController(alert, true, null);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void ShowMessage(string title, string message, string dismissButtonTitle, Action dismissed)
    {
        //var alert = UIAlertController.Create(title, message, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
        //alert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create(dismissButtonTitle, UIAlertActionStyle.Default,
        //         action => { if (null != dismissed) { dismissed.Invoke(); } }));

        //UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(alert, true, null);



        UIAlertController actionSheetAlert = UIAlertController.Create("App!!!", "\n" +
                                             "  " +
                                                                      "1. User Created", UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

        actionSheetAlert.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, action => { if (null != dismissed) { dismissed.Invoke(); } }));

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(actionSheetAlert, true, null);
    }
```

This is my working code

call it like this

```
ShowMessage("s", "s", "s", null);
```

"s" is just dummy text everything is done inside  ShowMessage()